# Gulp task does not run - becomes a callback for other tasks instead

Tags: gulp

I have a task that goes like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('doStuff', ['a', 'b', 'c'], function () {
    console.log("success");
});
```

I have read the [docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulptaskname-deps-fn), and from what I understood, this is what should happen:

- gulp creates a task called *doStuff*;
- gulp runs tasks *a*, *b* and *c* asynchronally;
- After all the three tasks above finish running, gulp runs the function I defined for *doStuff*.

This is what actually happens:

- gulp creates a task called *doStuff*;
- gulp runs tasks *a*, *b* and *c* asynchronally;
- gulp indicates it has run the *doStuff* task with success, but does not run the function I passed as the third parameter for the *gulp.task* method.

I was surprised to find out that if I accept a callback in the other functions, though, that callback is my function. I.e. if I do:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('a', function (callback) {
    callback();
});
```

This will run my code.

I'd like my function to be executed only once, and only after all other tasks have run. What am I missing, or misinterpreting? What can I do?

By the way, this may be relevant: most of my other tasks do things like generating files, and they return such files. Like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var someLogic = require('someLogicIImplementedSomewhereElse');
var path = "../../somepath";

gulp.task('foo', function() {
    return gulp.src(path)
        .pipe(someLogic())
        .pipe(rename("renamed.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path));
});
```

Comment: what do `a`, `b`, and `c` look like?  Do they return?

Comment: @DavinTryon They do return. I have edited my question to add a sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that a, b and c either return something or execute the callback.

Try the following example:

```
gulp.task('a', function (done) {
    done();
});

gulp.task('b', function (done) {
    return gulp.src('.');
});

gulp.task('c', function (done) {
    done();
});

gulp.task('stuff', ['a', 'b', 'c'], function () {
    console.log("success");
});
```

Here is the output of `gulp stuff`

```
- Starting 'a'...
- Finished 'a' after 48 μs
- Starting 'b'...
- Starting 'c'...
- Finished 'c' after 6.03 μs
- Finished 'b' after 9.14 ms
- Starting 'stuff'...
- success
- Finished 'stuff' after 38 μs
```

Comment: I have a rather novice question, how do you pass the "done" function thru the cli?

Comment: is this just like promise chains? seems like thats what it is, thenables.